# Hibernate / MySQL Bulk insert problem

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I'm having trouble getting Hibernate to perform a bulk insert on MySQL.

I'm using Hibernate 3.3 and MySQL 5.1

At a high level, this is what's happening:

```
@Transactional
public Set<Long> doUpdate(Project project, IRepository externalSource) {
    List<IEntity> entities = externalSource.loadEntites();
    buildEntities(entities, project);
    persistEntities(project);
}
public void persistEntities(Project project) {
     projectDAO.update(project);
}
```

This results in n log entries (1 for every row) as follows:

> Hibernate: insert into ProjectEntity (name, parent_id,
>   path, project_id, state, type) values
>   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

I'd like to see this get batched, so the update is more performant.  It's possible that this routine could result in tens-of-thousands of rows generated, and a db trip per row is a killer.

Why isn't this getting batched?  (It's my understanding that batch inserts are supposed to be default where appropriate by hibernate).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented in the [Chapter 13. Batch processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession):

> If you are undertaking batch
>   processing you will need to enable the
>   use of JDBC batching. This is
>   absolutely essential if you want to
>   achieve optimal performance. Set the
>   JDBC batch size to a reasonable number
>   (10-50, for example):
>
> ```
> hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
> ```
>
> Hibernate disables insert batching at
>   the JDBC level transparently if you
>   use an identity identifier generator.

Don't forget to `flush` and then `clear` the session regularly or you'll get `OutOfMemoryException` as documented in [13.1. Batch inserts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts).

But IMO, for tens-of-thousands of rows, you should consider using [the `StatelessSession` interface](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession).

Comment: Will this enable batching of SQL-statements? (Whether the sessions keeps state sounds rather orthogonal to batching, but perhaps I infer too much from the class name)

Comment: The part about the identifier generator is a little cryptic - this thread explains it: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2436697

Answer (score 7):

Pascal's answer is correct.  However, because you are using MySQL, I also highly recommend that you try using the `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` parameter in your JDBC URL.

This parameter causes the JDBC driver to dynamically re-write your INSERT batches to use a single "multi-valued" INSERT, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (2);
```

will be re-written to:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (0), VALUES (1), VALUES (2);
```

This can make a significant difference in some cases.  See http://www.jroller.com/mmatthews/entry/speeding_up_batch_inserts_for for some example measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Pascal has pretty much nailed it in hibernate context. As an alternative, you can use jbdc template's Batchsqlupdate. However I have to warn you that hibernate cached instances may not reflect the changes done using above. In our project, we had to take precautionary measures to overcome this, by creating a different schedule (another problem created, but within our control)