# Are batch inserts not working only because of the MySQL driver? What about others?

Tags: java, hibernate

Earlier I was trying to get batch inserts working in Hibernate. I tried everything: For the config I set batch_size(50), order_inserts(true), order_updates(true), use_second_level_cache(false), use_query_cache(false). For the session I used `setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)` and `setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL)`. Still the MySQL query log showed that each insert was coming in separately.

The ONLY thing that worked was setting `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` in the JBDC connection string. This worries me, as my application is supposed to support any JBDC database and I'm trying to avoid DB specific optimizations.

Is the only reason hibernate can't actually use batch statements because the MySQL driver doesn't support them by default? What about other drivers, do I have to add options to the connection string so they can support batched inserts? If you need specific db's, think SQL server, sqlite, Postgres, etc

Comment: We have no problems using batched updates using Oracle and Postgres. So maybe it *is* a driver problem. But I don't know Hibernate or MySQL good enough to actually answer this.

Comment: What generation strategy are you using for your `@Id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason it could not be working is that hibernate disables batching if you use the `Identity` id generation strategy.

Also MySQL doesn't support JDBC batch prepared statements the same way as other databases without turning on the rewrite option.

I don't see that it is a problem to turn this flag on though, if your are setting up your application for a different database you will have to change the settings such as dialect, driver name, etc. anyway and as this is part of the JDBC connect String then you are isolated from the configuration.

Basically I think you are doing the right thing.

Comment: This is an import application, so I'm actually using entity-maps which sidestep the problems with `@Id`. Big question though: Is it common to have to manually enable batched inserts in other drivers? As in the question think SQL server, sqlite, Postgres, etc

Comment: I can't really say if its common practice or not, but, the drivers are written by the database vendors themselves with the idea being to give the best performance for your use case so I would personally swing towards using the drivers batching feature, which is custom written for that db, than use a generic one like hibernate.  That said, using hibernate to do batching anyway at least guarantees some performance for less mature databases.

Answer (score 0):

As batch insert (or bulk insert) is part of the SQL standard, ORM frameworks like Hibernate support and implement it. Please see [Chapter 13. Batch Processing](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) and [Hibernate / MySQL Bulk insert problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303152/hibernate-mysql-bulk-insert-problem) .

Basically, you need to set the JDBC batch size via the variable named `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to a reasonable size. Also don't forget to end the batch transaction with `flush()` and `clear()`.

Comment: I am very familiar with the Batch Processing chapter. JDBC batch size was one of the first settings I set, I'm also flushing and clearing the Session I'm in. I'm not using StatelessSession since documentation says each save maps to an INSERT, meaning there's nowhere for batched statements to queue up

Comment: Sorry then. Also, congrats to StormBringerX! Cheers.